# Tools for tracking down un-closed tags

Tags: html

I'm trying to track down two missing closing div tags in a 2500 line html document, obviously I'm doing this manually but I remember that Visual Studio helpfully highlights the closing tag of the currently selected tag.

Don't have VS available but wondered if anyone knew of similarly helpful tool for this kind of task?

//update
Should probably say that I'm already using a validator and an editor with syntax highlighting - mainly I'm curious to find out what others use.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: or any editor with syntax highlighting for HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Firefox's add-on HTML Validator:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/

It works and you never have to leave your browser or copy/paste markup.

Answer (score 1):

W3C also has a great validation service.

http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely love Geany.  Haven't used it in a few months (forced to work on a .net project), but IIRC, it will do exactly what you need.

http://www.geany.org/